# Get Tomcat Java Settings

Tags: java, windows, testing, groovy, tomcat8

I want to write a test in groovy which will check Tomcat Java Settings, meaning those which user inputs in `Configure Tomcat -> Java -> Initial Pool Memory/ Max Pool memory`. Without having `CATALINA_OPTS` set or `setenv.sh` present.

Is this possible?

I searched everywhere in Tomcat folder for this information in order to extract it from the file where it is kept, but I didn't find it anywhere. Also, I tried to search for this information in Windows Registry, but I just found there Tomcat version and some other stuff that don't interested me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help I found where to get the values I needed. I searched in the wrong registry directory.
Right one is "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat8\Parameters\Java", but I searched in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat\8.5\Tomcat8".